# Storing multiple function values in a string/array (Python)

Tags: python, string, function

I am attempting to store multiple function values in an array, in order to graph a function in python.

For the example, let's define that the function is y= x^2 and the argument values wanted are 1,2 and 3. The code I attempted is the following :

```
def ExampleFunction (x):
        return x**2
ArgumentValues=range(3)       
FunctionValues=ExampleFunction(ArgumentValues)
```

Unfortunately running the code results in an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'range' and 'int'
```

How can I return many function values into a string/array in python? As a result I would want the "function values" take the following form:

```
1,4,9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
results = [ExampleFunction(x) for x in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code answer :

```
def ExampleFunction (x):
    list_fn = []
    for item in x :
        list_fn.append(item**2)
    return list_fn 
ArgumentValues=range(3)       
FunctionValues=ExampleFunction(ArgumentValues)
```

Or this code :

```
def ExampleFunction (x):
    return x**2
ArgumentValues=range(3)   
FunctionValues= [ExampleFunction(x) for x in ArgumentValues]
```

Comment: You are still returning only 1 value with your function.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect usage for [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
map(lambda x: x**2, range(3))
# [0, 1, 4]
```

In Python 3.X, `map` will return a `map object` instead of a list, so if you want to reuse it, you need to explicitly convert it to a `list`.